# Selecting a specific camera through Qt when multiple 'lenses' are present?

Tags: ios, qt, camera, qml, qt5

I have a Qt5.15 QWidgets application (targeted primarily for use on iOS).  I would like the user to be able to select a specific rear-facing camera of a phone that has multiple rear-facing cameras of different focal lengths.  (e.g.- the iPhone 12 has three rear-facing cameras: wide (0.5x), normal (1x) and telephoto (2.5x)).  Qt Quick solutions are also welcome.

`const QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();` Only returns two cameras on the iPhone (one front, one rear) even though there are really four (one front, **three** rear).

`QCameraFocus::zoomTo` can increase the digital zoom of the rear facing camera, but changing the optical zoom has no affect.  `QCameraFocus::maximumOpticalZoom` returns 1.0 for the rear camera as well.

How can I use any of the rear-facing cameras other than the default with Qt?